# Total less available = Remaining Formula in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have a bunch of statistical data that I have chopped up and pieced together in power query. In looks like there is category missing from the Database. To fill in the gaps I am trying to take the grand totals which are correct (red), subtract from that what I know to be correct, with the remaining numbers giving me my answer (orange).

The correct data starts with I1, I2, I3, I4, so possibly a grand total of these, by state.

At the moment this is filled by the following formula in excel;

`=E53-SUMIFS($E$5:$E$44,$B$5:$B$44,B45,$C$5:$C$44,C45,$D$5:$D$44,D45)`

Any help with how the heck I can do this in power query. I realise I cant use the same formula but any ideas would be much appreciated. I can change the text in red to total if that helps in some way?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one potential way. If you start with your spreadsheet set up similar to this:

[image]

*I only used a subset of your StateIDs from your example and generated my own Values for this example. And the figures in the Available column would be from your red section.*

Then add the table from the spreadsheet to Power Query (in Excel, you would click on the table and then Data > From Table/Range > Select My table has headers and click OK).

In Power Query:

You'll probably have to change the TimeID type to date if you want to use the dates for anything, because it will probably come in as date-time type--I won't use the dates here though, so you could skip changing the type (otherwise, right-click the TimeID column > Change Type > Date)

Then use Group By to aggregate values and set the stage for the calculation you want (select the StateID > Group By > and setup the groupings like below and click OK)

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]

Then add a new column with your calculation (Add Column > Custom Column > Set it up like below and click OK)

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks Marc,that was enough to get me though, thanks for that. 

I had to do about 40 other steps in total, as there was four data sets to slice and dice but I got there in the end!